# highlight row with different colors after date is entered in different column cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, highlighting, microsoft, column

We have a spreadsheet that tracks items by date in different columns. Item sent in column L, we would like it to be one color. but once the second date in entered column R. I am needing the row to change from one color to the other.

column L,  row highlight to beige for first entry, then, column R second entry the row highlight green

Comment: Could you provide a simple sample?

Answer (score 0):

If you know you will only enter dates, you can use the following conditional formatting.
How to format cells using the following formula.
=ISNUMBER($D1) (Date is nothing but a number)
Test it by pasting the format throughout your spreadsheet.

Comment: We have additional info on the spreadsheet. I am needing the row to change colors after a date is entered in a cell in different rows. I have one conditional format set for one column to change the row green after a date is entered, but i would like another column to change the row color.

Comment: enter date in Column R turns row green (within a selection of the spreadsheet). but the first date that i would enter would be row L. Row L would the the first place a date would be entered, then Row r and after a date is entered in Row R i would like it to change to a different color. CF now is =$R3<>$AG2